# CDN for production, local files for development

Tags: webpack

This has probably been answered before but I'm not sure if I'm using the right terminology or searching for the right thing.

I'd like to use a local version of 'bootstrap css' when doing local development, but for production I'd like the page to obtain the CSS from the CDN.

I'm using webpack for bundling my front end React + Redux. In my index.html I have a reference to the bootstrap css.

Is it [externals](https://webpack.github.io/docs/library-and-externals.html) that I need to use for webpack to switch between using a local css for dev and a CDN for prod? If so can anyone link any good examples that I could use for reference? I don't quite understand how I'm supposed to use the local bootstrap version. Do I npm install it, download the css manually into a folder?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing no one has answered it I'll answer with what I'm using. I'm using CSS Modules which I think is very powerful and allows CSS to be scoped to specific files. I achieve this by having the configuration below in my `webpack.config.js` file:

```
. . .
{
  test: /\.css$/,
  loader: 'style!css-loader?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]' 
}
. . .
```

See this link for more reference: https://github.com/css-modules/webpack-demo